# How to hide sheets upon login

Tags: excel, vba, database, userform

I am attempting to have a login page where the the sheets (lists, engine and admin) are hidden when the user is not admin, otherwise visible. The below code only hides the last sheet and all the others are visible to the user.

```
Private Sub okbtn_Click()
Dim Wksht As Worksheet
If Sheets("Admin").Range("B6").Value = True Then
Sheets("Admin").Range("B7").Value = Sheets("Admin").Range("B4").Value 'set current user

        login_UF.Hide
        
For Each Wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Wksht.Name = "Admin" Then
            If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
             End If
 If Wksht.Name = "Engine" Then
            If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
             End If
 If Wksht.Name = "Lists" Then
            If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
             End If

             
         Else: ' not admin
         Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
        
      
    Next Wksht
    
    
    Sheets("Admin").Range("B4,B5").ClearContents
    Sheets("Phonebook").Activate
    

Else
MsgBox "Please enter a correct username and password"
End If

End Sub
```

I tried the above and tried to play around with the loop but for some reason can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly then you do not need a loop to show/hide worksheet. This should help.

```
Dim VisibleStatus As Integer

If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then _
VisibleStatus = xlSheetVisible Else VisibleStatus = xlSheetVeryHidden

Sheets("Admin").Visible = VisibleStatus
Sheets("Engine").Visible = VisibleStatus
Sheets("Lists").Visible = VisibleStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

- Formatting code with proper `indentation` is a good coding practice as it helps identify and fix bugs more easily.
- Ensure to include `Next` and `End If` to maintain proper structure.
- The current code hides only the `Admin` sheet.
- The condition within `If Wksht.Name = "Engine" Then` in a `nested if` statement is always evaluated as `False`.

```vb
' OP's code in indentation w/o changes
Private Sub okbtn_Cldick()
    Dim Wksht As Worksheet
    If Sheets("Admin").Range("B6").Value = True Then
        Sheets("Admin").Range("B7").Value = Sheets("Admin").Range("B4").Value 'set current user
        login_UF.Hide
        For Each Wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Wksht.Name = "Admin" Then
                If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                    Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Else
                    Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                End If
                If Wksht.Name = "Engine" Then
                    If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                        Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                    Else
                        Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                    End If
                    If Wksht.Name = "Lists" Then
                        If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                            Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                        Else
                            Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                        End If
                    Else: ' not admin
                        Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                    End If
                Next Wksht
                Sheets("Admin").Range("B4,B5").ClearContents
                Sheets("Phonebook").Activate
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter a correct username and password"
            End If
        End Sub
```

- Simplify the code with `InStr`

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub okbtn_Click()
    Dim Wksht As Worksheet
    If Sheets("Admin").Range("B6").Value Then
        Sheets("Admin").Range("B7").Value = Sheets("Admin").Range("B4").Value 'set current user
        login_UF.Hide
        For Each Wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If InStr(1, "Admin|Engine|Lists", Wksht.Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                    Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Else
                    Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                End If
            Else
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
        Next
        Sheets("Admin").Range("B4,B5").ClearContents
        Sheets("Phonebook").Activate
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a correct username and password"
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008946)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, 
this didn't seem to work and triggered the msgbox to appear despite the username and password being correct.

Comment: The logic for showing the MsgBox is derived from your code. Please provide clarification on when you want the MsgBox to be displayed. Show it when Sheets("Admin").Range("B6").Value is not True?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use [taller's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77527243/16217248) to make some amendments to it per below to get it working.

```vb
Private Sub okbtn_Click()
    Dim Wksht As Worksheet
    If Sheets("Admin").Range("B6").Value = True Then
        Sheets("Admin").Range("B7").Value = Sheets("Admin").Range("B4").Value 'set current user
        login_UF.Hide
        For Each Wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If InStr(1, "Admin|Engine|Lists", Wksht.Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If Sheets("Admin").Range("B8").Value = "Yes" Then ' admin
                    Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                Else
                    Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                End If
            Else: ' not admin
                Wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
            Next
                Sheets("Admin").Range("B4,B5").ClearContents
                Sheets("Phonebook").Activate
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter a correct username and password"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The semicolon in `Else:` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

### Show/Hide Sheets When 'Logging Into Workbook'

```vb
Private Sub okbtn_Click()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
        
        If .Range("B6").Value = True Then ' username and password in 'B4,B5'?
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            
            .Range("B7").Value = .Range("B4").Value 'set current user
            'login_UF.Hide
            
            ' If user is 'Admin', in 'B8' is 'Yes'?
            Dim Visibility As XlSheetVisibility: Visibility = IIf( _
                .Range("B8").Value = "Yes", xlSheetVisible, xlSheetVeryHidden)
            
            Dim ws As Worksheet, SheetName As Variant
            
            ' Assuming the non-admin sheets are visible either way:
            For Each SheetName In Array("Admin", "Engine", "Lists")
                Set ws = .Parent.Sheets(SheetName)
                If ws.Visible <> Visibility Then ' incorrect visibility
                    ws.Visible = Visibility
                'Else ' correct visibility; do nothing
                End If
            Next SheetName
            
            .Range("B4,B5").ClearContents ' clear username and password?
            .Parent.Sheets("Phonebook").Activate
            
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else ' no username and/or password in 'B4,B5'?
            
            MsgBox "Please enter your username and password!", vbExclamation
        
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub
```